# What's this antique coin?

Tags: identification, numismatics

Reverse:
[image: Reverse]

Obverse
[image: Obverse] (click for full size)

Can anyone identify this coin?
I found it with other coin in a bag left by my father after he passed away.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like a rather poor copy of an [Athenian 'Owl' tetradrachm](https://www.moderncoinmart.com/info-vault/articles/athenian-owls.html). The portrait on the obverse is the goddess Athena.

The original coins were struck from silver as can be seen in [this example](http://www.britishmuseum.org/research/collection_online/collection_object_details.aspx?objectId=1120745&partId=1) from the British Museum collection:

[image: Athenian Owl Tetradrachm]

- Image copyright © British Museum (Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-ShareAlike 4.0 International (CC BY-NC-SA 4.0) license)

Comment: the dulling of the inscriptions hints to me, that it might be a *casted* copy.